# Why MongoDB create _entityWrapper C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I developing a web app with ASP.NET Web API 2 and MongoDB, all is ok but I don't know why in one Insert Mongo create an element in the document called _entityWrapper, and when I try to retrieve the  document is imposible to serialize the object. I attached a screenshot of document and exception in Visual Studio.

http://pastebin.com/d6XuHZZA

Thanx

Comment: Please include relevant code and the exception text as well as libraries used in your question.

Comment: You put picture of mongodb model in 'http://i.imgur.com/qJGkpdm.png'. but it doesn't seem picture of 'MGGenericGestion' class. something is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation properties of Entity Framework can cause this behaviour.

If you retrieve a model that includes navigation properties by using Entity Framework, and insert it in the next step to mongoDB, then you will see this behaviour.

Other than that it is just guessing based on your screenshots.